# SSE code for sum bytes. Where's the bug?

Tags: c, algorithm, visual-studio-2005, sse

I wrote SSE code for summing up byte values.
(VS2005.)

As it is simple enough it works quite well (and fast). Only there are crashes with some sizes of the array. And it crashes only in release mode - in debug never. Maybe someone sees the "obvious" bug?
Any help appreciated.

```
__int64 Sum (const unsigned char* pData, const unsigned int& nLength)
{
    __int64 nSum (0);

    __m128i* pp = (__m128i*)pData;

    ATLASSERT( ( (DWORD)pp & 15 ) == 0 ); // pointer must point to address multiple of 16 (cache line)

    __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128(),
        a, b, c, d, tmp;

    unsigned int i (0);

    for ( ; i < nLength; i+=64) // 4-fach loop-unroll (x 16)
    {
        a = _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero);           
        b = _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero);  // It crashes here.
        c = _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero);
        d = _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero);

        // commenting the following line prevents the crash (???)
        tmp = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_add_epi64( _mm_add_epi64( a, b ), c ), d);

        a = _mm_srli_si128 ( tmp, 8 );

        nSum += _mm_cvtsi128_si32( a ) + _mm_cvtsi128_si32( tmp );
    }

    // ... the rest
    if (nLength % 64)
        for (i -= 64; i < nLength; i++)
            nSum += pData [i];

    return nSum;
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
unsigned int nLength = 3571653;  // One of the values that causes crash
unsigned char *pData = (unsigned char*) _aligned_malloc(nLength, 16);
Sum (pData,  nLength);
```

Comment: Well, have you checked that `pp` is still in range?

Comment: Check the assembly differences between debug and release mode as release mode optimizations may have broken an assumption you make.

Comment: Does this scream premature optimisation to anyone else?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue no?

Comment: @harold Isn't it at all possible or likely that a compiler *might* automatically do this for you? Even in the case where that optimisation isn't done automatically, does summing up an array of `unsigned short`s seem too likely to be a bottleneck? That's fairly cache friendly; Perhaps there are other less cache-friendly areas that deserve a higher priority focus ;)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue OP is capable of using SSE intrinsics and knows "The `PSADBW` Trick", but you think he can't benchmark? Maybe... btw, OP is adding bytes, not shorts, contrary to what the title would have you believe.

Comment: @harold: OP is making assertions like "it works quite well (and fast) ... in debug". I find it difficult to believe that OP profiled his/her *original* solution (before injecting this code), in it's fully compiler-optimised form. If he/she did, he/she would know it makes no sense to benchmark unoptimised code. Perhaps, if he/she did, he/she would notice that GCC tends to perform SSE and loop unrolling optimisations automatically.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue OP is using VS2005, which doesn't auto-vectorize and even sucks at compiling intrinsics. And that selective quote isn't what he said.

Comment: Well, whoever this mysterious "OP" is ;-) ... I changed my mistake (short -> byte) so that the item may be found properly.
Moreover I learned that it's time for me to change to gcc etc.
(as actual versions of VS are unaffordable to me).
Thanks for participation and help.

Comment: @harold: Perhaps that suggests that OP needs to "benchmark" newer compilers... Perhaps a C compiler would be nice, though this code looks more like C++ (despite the tags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here's what I had in mind when I said "4 accumulators in the loop and summing them after the loop".

```
__int64 Sum (const unsigned char* pData, const int& nLength)
{
    __int64 nSum (0);

    __m128i* pp = (__m128i*)pData;


    __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128(),
        a = _mm_setzero_si128(),
        b = _mm_setzero_si128(),
        c = _mm_setzero_si128(),
        d = _mm_setzero_si128(), tmp;

    int i (0);

    for ( ; i < (nLength - 63); i+=64)
    {
        a = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero ), a );
        b = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero ), b );
        c = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero ), c );
        d = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_sad_epu8( *(pp++), zero ), d );
    }

    tmp = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_add_epi64( a, b ), _mm_add_epi64( c, d ));
    tmp = _mm_add_epi64( _mm_srli_si128( tmp, 8 ), tmp );
    nSum = (_mm_cvtsi128_si32( tmp ) & 0xFFFFFFFFULL) + 
               (((__int64)_mm_cvtsi128_si32( _mm_srli_si128( tmp, 4 ) )) << 32);

    // ... the rest
    for (; i < nLength; i++)
        nSum += pData [i];

    return nSum;
}
```

Comment: Great!
And to make it work for nLength < 63, the types of nLength and i should be int.

Comment: And on the other end, there's a problem too:
If nLength > 2^23+2^15 (about) somewhere there must be an overflow.
Don't know why & where (in the accumulators?).
Whereas "my old" version works fine up to INT_MAX.
This limit (2^23) is a serious restriction, because as an image it is 8 MegaPixel.

Comment: There you go, overflow fixed. On x64 it would be a lot easier, you could extract the sum with `_mm_cvtsi128_si64` there.

Answer (score 6):

Your for loop needs to be defined as follows:

```
for ( ; i < (nLength - 63); i+=64)
```

Basically imagine you pass in an array with nLength 120.  You are fine on the first run through.  i is now equal to 64.  i < 120 so you do another loop.  Unfortunately you pass the end of the array before you reach 128 and you enter into undefined behaviour territory.  This could manifest as an access violation (0xC0000005) which would cause you to crash.

Now take the example of nLength=128 which should run perfectly in your optimised loop with my suggested modification. First loop i is fine and i = 64.  i is less than 65 so another loop is performed.  i is now equal to 128 and loop exits.  The outer loop also doesn't run because i == nLength.  Job done :)

Comment: That's it - thank you! :-)
Although a bit embarrassing for me and my first post.
With the above fix, the "if (nLength % 64)" is unnesscessary then.
And the code is about 7 times as fast as without SSE (@ VS2005).

Comment: The second loop is then:
 // ... the rest
 for ( ; i < nLength; i++)
  nSum += pData [i];

Comment: @nji9 have you tried using 4 accumulators in the loop and summing them after the loop? It's quite a bit faster than this on my Core2.

Comment: @harold Wow - that's a good idea!
The only question: which type of accumulator? As you have take care on overflow. May I ask you to post the full code, so that someone interested in it doesn't have to puzzle it together from the fixes and suggestions? Greetings. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting into this kind of stuff myself, and I found [harold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15520419/934383) very helpful for something similar I am working on right now. However, an alternative suggestion I would like to make is that if it is not too much trouble for your application, have you considered padding your data with zeros at the end so that you don't need to perform this extra work at the end of your function?